# Infer date from number in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have column in a pandas DataFrame called `df['latestCertificationDate']`

It contains a series of numbers like this:

```
0       1570406400000
1       1479427200000
2       1506556800000
3       1527724800000
4       1490140800000
            ...      
4630    1473811200000
4631    1601337600000
4632    1585267200000
4633    1467158400000
4634    1484697600000
Name: initialCertificationDate, Length: 4635, dtype: int64
```

I know that each entry relates to a date. I have one reference that shows me the first entry `1570406400000` translates to `October 2019`.

Is there a way for me to infer the date or timestamp format and convert every entry in the series to the Month Year format?

I've tried using `date.fromtimestamp()` and it does seem to give the right output.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: That is in milliseconds.  Do` `date.fromtimestamp(x//1000)`.

Comment: Can you give a specific date and time for one of the numbers?

Answer (score 1):

using fromtimestamp of datetime and removing the last three zeros from the number, I get the following dates.

is that what you're looking for?

```
df['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp((x//1000)) ).to_frame()
```

```
        time
0       2019-10-06 20:00:00
1       2016-11-17 19:00:00
2       2017-09-27 20:00:00
3       2018-05-30 20:00:00
4       2017-03-21 20:00:00
4630    2016-09-13 20:00:00
4631    2020-09-28 20:00:00
4632    2020-03-26 20:00:00
4633    2016-06-28 20:00:00
4634    2017-01-17 19:00:00
```

Comment: Naveed, thank you! This approached worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.to_datetime(1570406400000) + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=597)
```

Output:

```
Timestamp('2019-10-01 00:26:10.406400')
```